# Send thumbnail with text - no app can perform this action - error

Tags: android, android-developer-api

I would like to display a small preview image of my content to be shared. However, when I run the code, I get a message that no app can perform this action. Unfortunately I don't know what's wrong

```
    private fun shareContentWithPreview() {
    val share = Intent.createChooser(Intent().apply {
        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/")
        type = "image/jpg"
        // (Optional) Here we're setting the title of the content
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Introducing content previews")

        // (Optional) Here we're passing a content URI to an image to be displayed
        val uri: Uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.one.myapplication/drawable/rome.jpg")

        data = uri


        flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
    }, null)
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, null))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi m8 think you are passing putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ...), and you should pass putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, ...) if you a re passing a Uri

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31248141)